# Shell command 'Join' not working

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, join

I am joining two very simple sorted files but for some strange reason it is not working. 
f1.txt:

```
f1 abc
f2 mno
f3 pqr
```

f2.txt:

```
abc a1
mno a2
pqr a3
```

Command:

```
join -t '\t' f1.txt f2.txt -1 2 -2 1 > f3.txt
```

FYI in the f1,f2 files the space is a tab.
But this is producing a blank f3.txt. Why is this happening? This is such a simple example of joining right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\t` isn't being interpreted as a tab character.  To do that you could/should use an ANSI string so your command would become

```
join -t $'\t' f1.txt f2.txt -1 2 -2 1 > f3.txt
```

with the `$` before the `'\t'` so it will be interpreted as a tab like you want.

A handy resource for quoting things with `bash` at least is available [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)

Comment: Hi thanks. it worked. I have just one more question if you know. whats the difference between sort -k2 and sort -k2,2 . I saw some examples but didnt understand quite well.

Comment: @ShabhriNaresh in general new questions should be asked as a new question, but for now if you do `-k2` it will do sorting from field 2 until the end of the line as part of the sort, `-k2,2` will do the sort based only on field 2, and not consider any other fields.  `-k2,3` would use just the second and third fields etc.  The first number is the first field to consider, the second is the last